# Can't connect usb printer with WebUSB API

Tags: usb, webusb

I have [DATECS DPP-250](http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/61) POS printer and I am trying to connect it using WebUSB API and print some data. Problem that I have is that printing is not working. I can connect to device and chrome reads it fine but when I submit printing (`transferOut`) printer just hangs. I tried to debug error in console but I don't have any errors whatsoever. I tried on MAC OS and on Windows 10 with WinUSB driver (used [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) to change driver on windows) and all of them have same problem.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

**EDIT:**

I tried with other POS printer (non bluetooth one) and my code works perfectly. Only problem is with this printer. This type of printer use micro usb so maybe that is a problem?

Here is code I am using

```
<html>
<body>
    <textarea id="printContent"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" onclick="connectAndPrint()" value="Print"/>
    <P>Type text into box and click on submit button.
    <script>
    var device;

    function setup(device) {
        return device.open()
        .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
        .then(() => device.claimInterface(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber))
    }

    function print() {
        var string = document.getElementById("printContent").value + "\n";
        var encoder = new TextEncoder();
        var data = encoder.encode(string);
        console.log(data.length);
        device.transferOut(device.configuration.interfaces[0].alternate.endpoints[0].endpointNumber, data)
        .catch(error => { console.warn(error); })
    }

    function connectAndPrint() {
        console.log(device);
        if (device == null) {
            navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 5380 }, { vendorId: 65520 }] })
            .then(selectedDevice => {
                device = selectedDevice;
                console.log(device.configuration);
                return setup(device);
            })
            .then(() => print())
            .catch(error => { console.log(error); })
        }
        else
            print();
    }

    navigator.usb.getDevices()
    .then(devices => {
        if (devices.length > 0) {
            device = devices[0];
            return setup(device);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What documentation are you using to know what commands to send to the printer?

Comment: I am using ESC/POS commands that are standard among POS printers.

Answer (score -1):

you need to run it on server for example with :xampp or node js. I was trying before with single html it doesnt work, but i put on server it will work

Comment: how did you fixed it on the server?